Trouble Integrating Calendar in French-Language Application: Issues with 'Locale' Property and Encoding
My application is in French, but when I try to integrate the showDatePicker, it appears in English instead of French. I tried using the " locale: Locale("en")," property, but it didn't work. Encoding also caused some issues. Therefore, I had to translate the entire project from English to French. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
I attempted to resolve the issue by adding the 'locale' property to my application, expecting it to ensure that the calendar displays dates in French. However, despite this effort, the problem persisted, with the calendar continuing to display dates in English. Strangely, upon restarting the application, the French language would briefly appear before reverting to English once again. Furthermore, I noticed that tapping the 'apply' button resulted in the entire project converting back to English. This behavior is unexpected and problematic, and I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure consistent French language display throughout the application, particularly within the calendar.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. A [mre], please? We love those around here. Read more here: Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.
